# Windows CE date-time synchronization with Windows Server 2003

Tags: sql, compact-framework, windows-server-2003, replication, windows-ce

My application (compact framework) works on Windows CE. The "cold boot" of the device resets the systemtime. Is there any way to synchronize systemtime with Windows Server 2003 (IIS) or using a merge replication on SQL Server 2000. 
I have a counted column in one of the datatables which counts current time but this row is somehow impossible to add to the publication.

I know there is a way to ask the SQL server but it's better not to use direct sql queries in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server is running an NTP time server, you can [query it directly](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2006/12/11/QueryingAnNTPSNTPTimeServer.aspx).